# Après « ensemble » est-ce qu'on met un pluriel ou un singulier ?

Tags: accord, pluriel, noms-collectifs

> L'ensemble d'ordinateurs en question sont non connectés à internet

Est-ce que cette phrase est correcte ? C'est-à-dire est-ce qu'on peut l'utiliser comme ça ?

Answer (score 2):

Pour les noms collectifs, la règle est de rester au singulier, sauf pour les adjectifs qui s'appliquent aux membres du groupe :

- le groupe de danseuses était resté devant la porte
- le groupe de danseuses qu'ils avaient accueilli**es**

Donc pour cette phrase précise :
L'ensemble d'ordinateurs en question n'est pas connecté à internet

Plus de détails :
http://www.aidenet.eu/conjugaison40.htm